# How to Deserialize the JSON response if it contains fields as test__c?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I am stuck as I have a response in the format shown below. Am not able to deserialize the fields appended with __c.

```
"ReviewDetail": [{
        "Request_Id__c": "",
        "Material_Requested_No__c": " ",
        "Material_Desc__c": " ”,
        "Quantity__c":"",
        "Unit__c":"",
        "Location":[{
            "Location_No__c":"",
            "Qty_In_Location__c":"",
            "Location_Desc__c":"",
            "Location_Type__c":"""
        }]
    },
        "Request_Id__c": "",
        "Material_Requested_No__c": " ",
        "Material_Desc__c": " ”,
        "Quantity__c":"",
        "Unit__c":"",
            "Location":[{
            "Location_No__c":"",
            "Qty_In_Location__c":"",
            "Location_Desc__c":"",
            "Location_Type__c":"""
}]]
}
```

And when I Try to deserialize this response through fields am not able to do it as it throws the error that "Request_Id__c is not an invalid identifier.

```
public class TrunkStockInterfaceWrapper {
    public class Location {
        public Integer Location_No__c {get; set;}
        public Integer Qty_In_Location {get; set;}
        public String Location_Desc {get; set;}
        public String Location_Type {get; set;}


    }

    public class ReviewDetail {
        public Integer Request_Id {get; set;}
        public Integer Material_Requested_No {get; set;}
        public String Material_Desc {get; set;}
        public Integer Quantity {get; set;}
        public Integer Unit {get; set;}
        public List<Location> Location {get; set;}
    }

    public List<ReviewDetail> ReviewDetail {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that your wrapper class variable names are different than what it is in the JSON.

`Request_Id__c` of JSON doesn't match with `Request_Id` of wrapper class `ReviewDetail`, same goes for every other variable.

You can change your wrapper class's variable names to match the JSON variable names so that the de-serialization method can find the matching fields.

Needless to say, do the same for `Location` class as well.

Comment: Yes , You are right  the json has Request_Id__c . But if I try to write this into my  wrapper class then it throws the error that "Request_Id__c is not an invalid identifier

Comment: Can you update your question with the wrapper class you are trying to save, with correct matching variable names?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the fields of your JSON object end in `__c` seems to indicate that this JSON is actually a serialization of a Salesforce custom object, not a class. I would look inside your Salesforce org to see if you have a custom objec that matches those fields (possibly called `ReviewDetail`?).

Otherwise, your best bet would be to create a custom object that matches those fields, and try to deserialize to it. Also, bear in mind you're deserializing an array, not a single object.

You can find some code for a similar solution here: [JSON String to custom object list](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79010/json-string-to-custom-object-list)